# -bash no such file or directory, but it exists

Tags: macos, bash, executable, alias, osx-lion

I've recompiled vim with the ruby flag for command-T awesomeness, and I wrote a script that will automatically do this for me on any machine I ssh into (and run the script), but an issue that I'm running into is that when I alias the newly compiled vim, bash throws a no such file or directory at me.  Here's what I have:

This works fine:

```
$  alias v="~/Code/vim"
```

But when I put this same line in my .bashrc, I get:

```
-bash: =~/Code/vim: No such file or directory
```

Even funnier, I put this in my .bashrc:

```
[ -e "~/Code/vim" ] && echo "found it!"
```

And that prints "found it!"

I'm not sure if it's a permission issue, but I'm just going to put them here anyway:

```
-rwxr-xr-x  1 buf  staff  2374400 Sep 17 16:27 /Users/buf/Code/vim
```

What am I doing wrong?  I'm running mac os x 10.7

Comment: Does it work without the quotes?

Comment: try "set -xv;. .bashrc; set +xv" to see what's going wrong with the parsing

Answer (score 2):

```
-bash: =~/Code/vim: No such file or directory
```

It looks like you forgot remove the **`=`** sign

Comment: @w00t: I know that. However, neither you or I can see inside his bashrc. What we _can_ see, however, is the error message. It must be triggered from somewhere