# Error installing Ruby without Xcode Command Line Tools: No such file, but it exists

Tags: ruby, macos, bash, compiler-errors, rvm

I'm installing RVM & Ruby without Xcode's Command Line Tools (on Mac OS X 10.8.2 (12C60) (Mountain Lion) with Xcode 4.5 (4G182)).

RVM installs fine. But, when I try to install Ruby, I get `error: limits.h: No such file or directory` https://gist.github.com/3789921#L241.

But, that file exists there because `cat` works and so does:

```
$ file /usr/local/Cellar/apple-gcc42/4.2.1-5666.3/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-apple-darwin11/4.2.1/include/limits.h
/usr/local/Cellar/apple-gcc42/4.2.1-5666.3/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-apple-darwin11/4.2.1/include/limits.h: ASCII c program text
```

So, why does bash say it doesn't exist?

The following questions are similar but unhelpful:

- ["No such file or directory" but it exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3949161/no-such-file-or-directory-but-it-exists)
- ['No such file or directory' error in bash, but the file exists?](https://superuser.com/questions/344533/no-such-file-or-directory-error-in-bash-but-the-file-exists)
- [-bash no such file or directory, but it exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7459037/bash-no-such-file-or-directory-but-it-exists)

Comment: Not necessarily a criticism, but I know I started to move away from the manual-install method when I found JewelryBox: http://unfiniti.com/software/mac/jewelrybox

Comment: How do you know that Ruby is trying to load "limits.h" from the same path you have listed?  You say that bash says it does not exist, yet the error message does not say `bash`.

Comment: Which command do you use to install Ruby, from which directory? It probably doesn't know that it should look in `/usr/local/...`. On Linux I would use `strace` to look at the full file paths that were tried by the installation program.

Comment: Any reason you don't have the command line tools installed? This is necessary to use a lot of different gems.

Comment: @cdarke the error in the question linked to the gist, but I realized that wasn't obvious, so I separated it out.

Comment: Udated the title to actually mention ruby, xocde, etc.

Comment: @tadman Similar to this reasoning: https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/issues/1138. I have all the files on my system already. Installing the Command Line Tools just copies them into my system folders. I'd rather keep my system folders clean (a Homebrew principle) and tell the compiler to look in `xcode-select -print-path` instead. Also, Homebrew now works without installing the Command Line Tools.

Comment: I don't know how installing Apple produced software in your OS X system folder is somehow making things dirty. The command-line tools provide `/usr/bin/gcc` as well as the usual `/usr/include` stuff that a lot of programs expect. That you got it working without this is surprising. I didn't know that was possible.

Comment: @tadman I guess by clean, I meant DRY. Yea, I might just install them, but it'd be cool not to have to. So, I might try for a bit more... :)

Answer (score 2):

You need to install osx-gcc-installer (or command-line-tools + gcc-4.2) to make it working.

Read `rvm requirements` for information what is need for proper ruby installation.